# The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it. error in mysql image

Tags: mysql, docker

after I changed data directory of docker (i.e /etc/docker/daemon.json), I get the following error while I'm trying to run mysql image

```
2022-07-13T10:31:27.580551Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2022-07-13T10:31:27.584905Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2022-07-13T10:31:27.588941Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file inside "/tmp"; errno: 13
2022-07-13T10:31:27.588965Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012929] [InnoDB] InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2022-07-13T10:31:27.589074Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-07-13T10:31:27.589091Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2022-07-13T10:31:27.589141Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-07-13T10:31:27.589437Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: In my case a custom health check was the cause

Answer (score 2):

The "real" problem is shown earlier in this line:

```
2022-07-13T10:31:27.588941Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012576] [InnoDB] Unable to create temporary file inside "/tmp"; errno: 13
```

MySQL seems to have problems writing your `/tmp` directory. Please check the permissions for the directory and/or the docker configuration.

After this is fixed you can remove the mentioned data directory (`/var/lib/mysql`) and try again. But please be careful if you had any existing databases in the directory before ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Always been having issues with this when I freshly install ubuntu in another device.

The fix for this is to remove your docker volume.

Try running `docker volume ls` and check if there is an existing volume created. Which in my case I had already an existing one, that's why it says `/var/lib/mysql` is unusable the last time.

Just run `docker volume rm <volume_name>` then run again your docker normarlly.

Hope this helps.